# subversion: change in revision number without any activity in the repository?

Tags: svn, jenkins

I had enabled polling option in jenkins, so that it scans the svn repository for changes and auto-triggers a build. But there were few builds which ran even though there were no scm changes and when i checked the polling log, i saw the below message

**Polling Log
Started on Sep 18, 2013 9:08:40 AM
Received SCM poll call for ABC on Sep 18, 2013 9:10:35 AM
https://svnrepositoryXYZ.com/projectXXX/ABC is at revision 29,323
  (changed from 29,313)
Done. Took 3.2 sec
Changes found**

It seems the revision number had changed even though there were no changes in the SVN repository. Is this a jenkins polling problem or a sync issue between the jenkins server and SVN repository. Any ideas because i am clueless?

Comment: why do you say that nothing has changed in SVN repo ? (look at changes between rev 29313 and rev 29323 in SVN : I don't thing SVN will create new revisions when there is no commit)

Comment: The reason is because, when i click on the changes tab for that particular link in jenkins, i dont see any updates. any clue?

Comment: use `svn log -r 29313:29323`, forgot dumb external GUIs

Comment: Strangely, the revision number that is dislayed in jenkins does not reflect the revision number when i did the SVN log. Jenkins scm poll log says rev changed from r2 to r3 but the revision number in the build log still shows up as r2.